# Using JOINS in MySQL, an additional table is created?

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

```
SELECT d.user_guid AS dUserID, c.user_guid AS cUserID, d.dog_guid AS dDogID,
c.dog_guid AS dDogID, count(test_name)
FROM dogs d LEFT JOIN complete_tests c
ON d.dog_guid=c.dog_guid
GROUP BY d.dog_guid;
```

When writing this code, a table was created that was labeled..."dDOGId_1"

the output is virtually the same with the exception of some that have the word "non" in the rows

Is this where the JOIN is happening? Also where is this coming from? Is there something wrong in my code that is creating this additional column?

Comment: Both `d.dog_guid` and `c.dog_guid` has been given alias of `dDogID`. The 2nd one (`c.dog_guid`) appears to be named `dDogId_1`. Change `c.dog_guid AS dDogID` to `c.dog_guid AS Complete_Tests_dDogID` and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What?  You seem very confused.  This is your `select`:

```
SELECT d.user_guid AS dUserID, c.user_guid AS cUserID, d.dog_guid AS dDogID,
       c.dog_guid AS dDogID, count(test_name)
```

No addition *table* is created.  Your result has two columns called `dDogID`.  To distinguish between them, the application is adding a `_1`.

However, including both is entirely unnecessary, because the `left join` implies they are the same.  And the `count()` should be counting matches.  I assume this is the query you intend:

```
SELECT d.user_guid AS dUserID, d.dog_guid AS dDogID,
       count(c.test_name)
FROM dogs d LEFT JOIN
     complete_tests c
     ON d.dog_guid=c.dog_guid
GROUP BY d.dog_guid;
```

The `c.user_guid` doesn't really make sense in the `SELECT`, because it is unclear what row it should be coming from.  Perhaps you want `MIN(c.user_guid)`, a `MAX()`, or `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Got ya. I understand. I was confused, hence why i asked the question. I didnt understand why it was creating the additional table and labeling it _1 without me putting that in the syntax after the AS statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have 2 columns labeled with the same name. So the second one is defaulted to _1

It has nothing to do with the join

Comment: Also don't forget to mark the answer :). Check mark on the side.